# Converting elements under List<String[]> to upper case in one go

Tags: java, string

I am using a `List<String[]>` with a few smaller case fields.

```
List<String[]> csvBody = reader.readAll();
```

My output should be of the same datatype `List<String[]>`.

Is there a possibility to convert every String in my Container to uppercase in a stretch?

Comment: What's your ouput structure? Still `List<String[]>` ? Do you want to retain the original non-uppercases version of String?

Comment: I have updated my answer Manh. Please refer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just iterate the strings:

```
List<String[]> csvBody = reader.readAll();
for (String[] strings : csvBody) {
    for (int i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) {
        strings[i] = strings[i].toUpperCase();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. It worked ! Accepting Jacob.G's answer based on the response time.

Comment: @Mike If you're concerned about speed, Neng's answer will be faster than mine.

Comment: Genuine of you Jacob. Will go with Neng !

Answer (score 6):

I reckon you can use a combination of `List#replaceAll` and a `Stream` to map the arrays:

```
csvBody.replaceAll(a -> Arrays.stream(a)
                              .map(String::toUpperCase)
                              .toArray(String[]::new));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. It worked Jacob. Accepting your answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<String[]> result = csvBody.stream()
        .map(strings -> Arrays.stream(strings)
                .map(String::toUpperCase)
                .toArray(String[]::new))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

It creates a stream of `String[]`, converts each String to upper case and returns an array containing the (upper-cased) string. At last, the individual String[] are collected it into a *new* list

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. It worked ! Accepting Jacob.G's answer based on the response time.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to retain the original String version, I think the most concise and easy way is to convert your line to uppercase when you read it from `reader`

```
String line = reader.readLine().toUppercase();
```

If you want to retain the original String so this can help:

```
   list.stream().map(a -> Arrays.stream(a).map(String::toUppercase).toArray(String[]::new))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response Manh. I wish to retain the original version though ! Accepting Neng Liu's answer based on the response time.